# Concurrency issues in java accessing Jdbc Impala

Tags: java, multithreading, resultset, impala

What I want to do: Have two thread t1,t2 where t1 connecting to I1 impala cluster and t2 connecting  to I2

Both t1 and t2 has the task of executing set of queries in the respective databases.

Below is the pseudo code:

```
    queriesMap(queryName,query)//got the queries dynamically from another table, customized and set to map here

    myThreadMethod(queriesMap, connUrl)
   {
   conn = getImpalaConnection(connUrl)
   stmt = conn.createStatement()
   for each query in queriesMap
   {
       ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
       ResultSetMetadata rsMetadata = rs.getMetadata();
       rs.next(); //assuming retrieving only the sum- only one row
       for(i=1;i<=rsMetadata .getColumnCount();i++)
      {
          //append column names and print
          //append result values and print
      }
    }
    }
```

Now the column and result values that are being printed are not the same way every time. if the same code is run without threads, the results are as expected.
Note: I have tried threadlocal but it didn't help

Could anyone please let me know what could be causing issue here?

Expected Result:
Thread1

```
 Query1   q1-C1 q1-C2 q1-C3 q1-c4 q1-c5
          q1-V1 q1-V2 q1-V3 q1-V3 q1-V5

 Query2  q2-C1 q2-C2 q2-C3 
         q2-V1 q2-V2 q2-V3 

 Query3  q3-C1 q3-C2 q3-C3 q3-c4 q3-c5
         q3-V1 q3-V2 q3-V3 q3-V3 q3-V5
```

Thread2

```
 Query1   q1-C1 q1-C2 q1-C3 q1-c4 q1-c5
          q1-V1 q1-V2 q1-V3 q1-V3 q1-V5

 Query2  q2-C1 q2-C2 q2-C3 
         q2-V1 q2-V2 q2-V3 

 Query3  q3-C1 q3-C2 q3-C3 q3-c4 q3-c5
         q3-V1 q3-V2 q3-V3 q3-V3 q3-V5
```

Result I am currently getting and this is not always the same, only for an example:  q1-c1 column1 of query 1 , q1-v1 value/result 1 of query 1

Thread1:

```
 Query1   q1-C1 q1-C2 q1-C3 q1-c4 q1-c5
          q1-V1 q1-V2 q1-V3 q1-V3 q1-V5

 Query2  q2-C1 q2-C2 q2-C3 
         q2-V1 q2-V2 q2-V3 

 Query3  q3-C1 q3-C2 q3-C3 q3-c4 q3-c5
         q3-V1 q3-V2 q3-V3 q3-V3 q3-V5
```

T2:

```
 Query1  q1-C1 q1-C2 q1-C3 q1-c4 q1-c5
         q1-V1 q1-V2 q1-V3 q1-V3 q1-V5

 Query2  q2-C1 q2-C2 q2-C3 
         q2-V1 q2-V2 q2-V3 

 **Query3  q2-C1 q2-C2 q2-C3 
         q3-V1 q3-V2 q3-V3**
```

As shown from expected and current results, issue is with thread2 Query3 there is jumbling of column metadata. This result is not consistent, there is issue once with Query1, once with Query2 etc

Comment: If two threads print data to the same file/console then it may be printed in interleaving order. Instead of thread1-col1,thread1-col2, thread1-col3, thread2-col1, thread2-col2, thread2-col3 messages might be printed in any order. Could you please provide expected and actual printer results to your question?

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have edited my question with expected and actual results. Please let me know if anything is not clear

Comment: Looks like kind of race condition and because of that thread2 executes one query two times

Comment: In the current result i have given query 2 columns for query 3 but in real i have more than 3 queries and it doesnt look like repeating the queries, like 7th query have columns of 3rd query for example. It looks like a race condition though but cannot think of a solution to avoid this issue ( I am using ExecutorService)